# Parse query doesn't continue when connection issue occurs

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine

When we make a call to ParseCloud.CallFunctionAsync or ParseObject.GetQuery(...).FindAsync() function and the internet connection fails during the call, the function never gives any error or times out or throws an exception. It just sits there indefinitely and it never continues into the callback function. Below is an example. We need a way to catch that scenario so we can display a proper message to the user.

Does anyone have advice on the best way to get an error from parse and how to catch it if the connection fails during the call.

Thanks

```
  

    try
    {
    var query = ParseObject.GetQuery(...);
           query.FindAsync().ContinueWith(t => {
             try {
                if (t.IsFaulted || t.IsCanceled)
                {
                   Debug.Log("Error Exception: " + t.Exception);
                    foreach(var e in t.Exception.InnerExceptions) {
                    ParseException parseException = (ParseException) e;
                    Debug.Log("Error message: " + parseException.Message);
                    Debug.Log("Error code: " + parseException.Code);
                }

                else {
                         //handle normal situation
                         ....

                  }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log(e.ToString());
            }
          });
      }
    catch(Exception e2)
    {
           Debug.Log(e2.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In parse there you can handle errors for many things.

I think to stop a query if there is not internet connection you can use kPFErrorConnectionFailed

Ex.

```
var query = PFQuery()
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{
(success:Bool!, error:NSError!)-> Void in
                    if (error == nil) {

                      //continue query
                    }
                    else{
                        // 100 is the kPFErrorConnectionFailed which is for your scenario 
                        if(error.code == 100) {
                            //handle error

                        }


                }     

        }
```

Something to note though in newer parse frameworks they are now handled by the code number and not name, you will need to search for the error codes to handle specific scenarios.

Here is a link with all the error codes from parse https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Constants/PFErrorCode.html